# Node.js RabbitMQ messages lost if receiver is not running

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

This is the problem that I am having

1.If the receiver is started first and then send a message the message is delivered

2 But if the receiver is not started then the code says message sent but starting the receiver does not get the message .

If I try the same sequence in python using pika things seem to work normally .

I also verified that there are no messages using the rabbitmqctl --list_queues command

I am running node.js 0.70 and running on a Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit version

I have the following code in my send.js

```
   var util= require('util')
   var amqp = require('amqp');

   var connection = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',
                                    login:'guest',
                                    password:'guest'});
   var pubMessage = function pubM(msg) {
   var x = connection.exchange();
   var q = connection.queue('helloNode',
            { autoDelete: true, durable: false, exclusive: false }
   );
   x.publish('helloNode',{helloNode: "This is a message"});
   };

   connection.addListener('ready', pubMessage);
   console.log(" Sent a message ");
```

and the following code in my receiver

```
   var util= require('util')
   var amqp = require('amqp');
   var connection = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',
                                    login:'guest',
                                    password:'guest'});

   connection.on('ready', function () {
   var q = connection.queue('helloNode',
            { autoDelete: true, durable: false, exclusive: false }
   );
   q.bind('#');

   q.subscribe(function (message) { 
            util.p(message);
   });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue binding is being set with autoDelete: true.  With this set, if the receiver isn't connected (or when it disconnects) then there is no queue to route messages to. Setting autoDelete: false leaves the queue intact even if the receiver goes offline and will continue accruing messages.

Comment: Setting autoDelete: false worked . The only thing was that I had to restart the rabbitmq server after making the change since I was using the same queue name . Actually I was running on my laptop and the laptop rebooted

Answer (score 0):

Message is routed to "helloNode" queue and then, when your sender terminates this queue is  deleted. This is the case even with "exclusive:false" because there is a subscription to this queue created in your sender. Given this, behavior "if no subscription has been ever active on the queue it will not get auto-deleted" does not apply here.

Maybe pika creates exchanges/queues with different values ?